Sync Layernotes between Projects
Is there a way to let the layernotes of one shapefile show up and update in multiple different projects?
I would like to leave some notes for my colleagues, having the same shapefiles but in different projects.

Layer note are stored in QGIS project, they are not part of the data themselves (you can have different note for the same data layer in different project). see this for more information
So unless you share the same project with you colleagues they wont see your note simple by loading the same layer.
That being said, from the above link :

layer notes are also supported by and stored within QML (QGIS Style)
and QLR (QGIS Later Definition) and can be copied and pasted using the
traditional copy/ paste methodology for transferring styles between
layers in QGIS files.

so you can share note layer with your colleagues by sending them a QML file for exemple (of course you will need to send a new QML file each time you update the note and your colleague will need to remember to check if they are using the latest version, so this not a viable long term solution unless you are able to automate this procedure).
Alternatively you may use the layer metadata or create a "real" layer with a default symbology to act as a notes.
